Change audio for specific application in python on windows
i try to make a programm that can split audio and one of the problems i face is how can i change the audio output for one specific application f.x. opera
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
import psutil


def change_audio_output(device_name):
    prog_name = i_name
    devices = AudioUtilities.GetAllDevices()

    device = next((d for d in devices if d.FriendlyName == device_name), None)

    if not device:
        print(f"Device '{device_name}' not found.")
        return

    print(f"Selected device: {device.FriendlyName}")

    sessions = AudioUtilities.GetAllSessions()

    session_found = False
    for session in sessions:
        process = session.Process
        if process and process.name().lower() == f'{prog_name}.exe'.lower():
            print(f"Found session for '{prog_name}.exe'")
            volume = session._ctl.QueryInterface(IAudioEndpointVolume)
            volume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(0.5, None)
            session_found = True
            break

    if not session_found:
        print(f"No session found for '{prog_name}.exe'")


i_name = input('Prog: ').strip()

change_audio_output("CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)")


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Users\Angel\PycharmProjects\audio_projects\change_out.py", line 36, in 
change_audio_output("CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)")
File "D:\Users\Angel\PycharmProjects\audio_projects\change_out.py", line 25, in change_audio_output
volume = session._ctl.QueryInterface(IAudioEndpointVolume)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Users\Angel\PycharmProjects\audio_projects.venv\Lib\site-packages\comtypes_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 520, in QueryInterface
self.__com_QueryInterface(byref(iid), byref(p))  # type: ignore
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147467262, 'No such interface supported', (None, None, None, 0, None))

